# SQL Injection on double table

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

If an SQL Injection on the address bar (like `?ID=1`) affects two tables (`SELECT *FROM catalogue WHERE...` and `SELECT *FROM reviews WHERE...`) with a different amount of columns, how could a hacker inject their SQL (edit: i.e. see all tables)? For example, '`UNION`ing' a value from `dual` to the queried result.

Table 1 (`?ID=[row]`):

```
mp3s || COL1 | COL2 | COL3  ... COL5    <-- 5 columns
-----++------+------+------
-----++------+------+------
mp31 || ...  | ...  | ...
-----++------+------+------  
mp32 || ...  | ...  | ...
  :
  '
mp39
```

Table 2 (`?ID=[row]`):

```
revs || COL1 | COL2 | COL3  ... COL19   <-- 19 columns
-----++------+------+------
-----++------+------+------
r001 || ...  | ...  | ...
-----++------+------+------  
r002 || ...  | ...  | ...
  :
  '
r185
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is truly being used for two queries and those queries are selecting a different number of columns there is no `UNION` SQL Injection attack that will work for both.  It's not possible to select two different number of columns at once.

It may be possible to perform other types of SQL Injection attacks like:

`ID=1 OR 1=1`

but you will need to experiment to see if that is possible in your particular situation.

Comment: Those last ones work, but I can't get in.